# Why is my app not crashing when same managed object context is used in different threads?

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios6, grand-central-dispatch, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I m trying to create a sample app with multi-threading and core data which is either suppose to crash or be in a deadlock.

I have created a concurrent queue and using a for loop call dispatch_async thrice.

```
     AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication       sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *aMangedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

for (int i = 0; i<=2; i++) {     

    LibXMLParser *parser = [[parserClass alloc] init];
    parser.delegate = self;
    dispatch_async(_queue, ^{
        [parser startWithContext:aMangedObjectContext];

    });
}
```

//I added another concurrent queue just to see if it crashes, but had no luck

```
    for (int i = 0; i<=2; i++) {
    LibXMLParser *parser = [[parserClass alloc] init];
    parser.delegate = self;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [parser startWithContext:aMangedObjectContext];

    });
}
```

I create concurrent queue using this technique:

```
@property (nonatomic) dispatch_queue_t queue;
@property (nonatomic) dispatch_queue_t queue;

_queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
_queue1 = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
```

I save data in main context:

```
 AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *aMangedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
NSError *error = nil;
 if (![aManagedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error in adding a new bank %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

Here m using the same main context created in my app delegate in different threads.
And since this breaks the containment model in core data, (each thread should have its own private context) my app should not generate the proper output.

The app gets top 100 songs in each dispatch_async. so totally i get 300 songs.

I haven't registered my app to NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification either, since i have used only the main context and not multiple.
each time save is called in different threads on the main context it self.

I just don't understand why my app is neither in deadlock nor is it crashing.

can any one tell me where i have gone wrong.

I just want my app to either crash or freeze when using same object context in multiple threads when i use one context in different.

Can someone tell me in what case a queue will access the same context simultaneously.Should i create another concurrent queue? I tried that and it did not work.

Thank you.

Comment: CoreDatas managed object context is not thread save. Thus you can't just use the context in an other thread. Best solutions is multiple contextes, one per thread. Cocoanetics has a nice blog post about this: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/

Comment: I m aware of that. I just have a doubt why the app is not freezing or crashing.

Comment: Altough not being thread save if you are just writing data from one thread and not doing any thing in an other thread with the context nothing will go wrong. Your app will crash when two thread will access the same context at the same time.

Comment: okay. So in the dispatch_async the method [parser startWithContext:aMangedObjectContext]; gets xml data of top 100 from a url and after every 20 songs parsed, save is called on particular context that belongs to that particular thread. Since m calling the same method in dispatch_async thrice, three threads created are either parsing data or saving, and any two threads are not saving it into core data simultaneously, if it doesn't crash? So this means that it may crash when same context is used?

Comment: No, since you call the save in the dispatch_async and you are calling it from an other thread. It does not crash because all your threads are running in the save queue. It will not perform the the parse block until it is finished with the previous one. Thus the context is never really accessed by two threads at the same time.

Comment: okay.I m using same context created in app delegate in all the other threads created. So in the dispatch_async the method [parser startWithContext:aMangedObjectContext]; gets xml data of top 100 from a url and after every 20 songs parsed, save is called on particular context that belongs to that particular thread. Since m calling the same method in dispatch_async thrice, three threads created are either parsing data or saving. if it doesn't crash or freeze, then any two threads are not saving it into core data simultaneously?

Comment: But i have three separate parsers in each thread. What is save queue? and the queue created is a concurrent queue.

Comment: Have you read my previous comment, they are all saving. But GCD will execute them in order that they are added to the queue since you have the one queue on which you add the blocks.

Comment: okay now i get you..thanx a lot. just one last question though, Is this approach correct if i use 3 different context for three threads created above. Wat if i add another concurrent queue and call the same method? I just tried that and it didin't crash.

Comment: I would really suggest you read the blog post posted in my first comment. This will explain some option for multi threaded coredata context.

Comment: Just wanted to get a crash in the app.